# Usage of Hashmap as thread safe in parallel test execution

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, automated-tests

I have a class used to generate random values and put these random values into a hashmap.  But  I have configured the test suite to be able to execute paralley. So, I have declared constroctor as private to be thread-safes this hashmap.  Is this mechanism right?. If it is incorrect, how can I achieve it?

```
public  class RandomData{
    private static Hashmap map = new Hashmap();

    private RandomData(){}

    public String getRandomVal(){

        /* generate random value and put the map, if this generated 
         value is not existing in the map, it will return or else 
         a new value is generated again and return. */
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific what are key/values of this map. can you post an example of your random value generation and storing?

Answer (score 2):

You have a single instance of a `HashMap`, that is shared between all the instances of `RandomData`. If multiple threads try to update it (by calling `getRandomVal`) concurrently, you may get undefined behavior, since `HashMap` is not thread-safe. You could solve this by using a thread-safe implementation of `Map`, such as [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: Having watched C++ and Java tags for more than 4 years, this is the first time I see someone mention Undefined Behaviour in Java. Care to explain what do you mean? From what I know, there is no UB in Java with concurrent modification - you just may end up with ConcurrentModificationException. Can your data get corrupted in such a way that the whole program is ill-formed, like in C++?

Comment: @Fureeish `ConcurrentModificationException` can even happen in a single thread - e.g., if you modify a collection while iterating over it with an `Iterator`. WRT undefined behavior - perhaps that wasn't the greatest phrasing. But it's definitely undeterminable - it may work fine if you hit the map in the right timing, it may cause `Map#get` to end up in an endless loop that will cause the entire program (or at least the thread executing it) to get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMaps` are not thread safe. Making a variable/method does not make it thread-safe.You should use `ConcurrentHashMaps or HashTable` for thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

No just making constructor private doesn't make class thread safe

```
 public static class RandomData {
        private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        private RandomData() { }

        public String getRandomVal() {

        /* generate random value and put the map, if this generated
         value is not existing in the map, it will return or else
         a new value is generated again and return. */

        }


    }
```

Use ConcurrentHashMap and its methods:

look at:

```
ConcurrentHashMap::computeIfAbsent
ConcurrentHashMap::putIfAbsent
```

these methods are atomic and guaranteed to be safe.